# Getting unorderable types on Pandas' clip on column with only numerical data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on my first Pandas data exploration notebook and I encountered an issue with some Pandas operations like the title's `clip`.

I have a data frame with following columns and datatypes:

`kairaId               object
sex                   object
primaryPerson           bool
birthDay             float64
birthMonth           float64
birthYear            float64
deathYear            float64
ownHouse              object
returnedKarelia       object
previousMarriages     object
pageNumber            object
sourceTextId          object
professionId           int64
professionName        object
placeName             object
region                object
stemmedName           object
extractedName         object
latitude             float64
longitude            float64
children_count         int64
migration_count      float64
dtype: object`

I want to remove some outlier rows based on longitude. I thought Pandas' `clip` would do the trick:

`df = df.clip(None, upper=50.0, axis='longitude')`
This however results in `TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= float()`.

I realize that Pandas is trying to compare strs and floats which results to an error in Python 3, but I don't understand why, nor how to circumvent this issue. Apparently some other column's contents interfere with this? I also got the error when trying some other Pandas operations.

[More context in the form of Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/Tumetsu/hands-on-machine-learning-exercises/blob/master/karelia.ipynb)

Is there something fundamentally wrong in my data frame? Any docs which are related to this issue? I just picked Pandas this evening so I'm not yet sure which docs are relevant or how the data frames operate under the hood. I'll probably pick up a book about the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the use of `df.clip` - it is meant to conform outliers to some particular outer bound, not remove them. An example from the docs:

```
df

          0         1
0  0.335232 -1.256177
1 -1.367855  0.746646
2  0.027753 -1.176076
3  0.230930 -0.679613
4  1.261967  0.570967

df.clip(None, 0.5)

          0         1
0  0.335232 -1.256177
1 -1.367855  0.500000
2  0.027753 -1.176076
3  0.230930 -0.679613
4  0.500000  0.500000
```

Also, the `axis` argument would refer to 0, or 1 (applied along row or columns). It does not refer to the columns at all.

In your case, you want to remove all records associated with an outlier longitude. For this, you should use something along the lines of `df.filter`, `df.mask`, `df.query`, or even just `boolean indexing`:

```
mask = (df.longitude <= 50.0)
df = df[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I misunderstood the clip then.